# How can I capture date intervals dynamically using recursion or another method in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I have this in a CTE in Redshift:

```
select
cast('2021-03-31' as date) as contract_start_date,
cast('2025-03-30' as date) as contract_end_date,
datediff(month, '2021-03-31', '2025-03-30') as number_of_months,
'abc' as client_id;
```

I want to output a long table that captures the date every six months starting from the contract_start_date to the contract_end_date. The output of the code should look like this:

```
client_id   date_interval
abc         9-30-21
abc         3-30-22
abc         9-30-22
abc         3-30-23
abc         9-30-23
abc         3-30-24
abc         9-30-24
abc         3-30-25
```

I know that I can hard code this using dateadd functions in separate CTEs, but contract durations can vary widely. I prefer to have dynamic code that, starting with the enddate, subtracts 6 months iteratively until 0 months remain, capturing each date in a separate row with each iteration. Can this be done recursively? If this is too complicated in Redshift, I can probably do it in Python, but that is a last resort and performance will suffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift recently added [support for recursive queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html#r_WITH_clause-recursive-cte): yay!

I think the logic you want is:

```
with recursive cte (client_id, date_interval, end_date) as (
    select client_id, contract_start_date from mytable
    union all
    select client_id, dateadd(month, 3, date_interval), end_date
    from cte
    where date_interval < end_date
)
select client_id, date_interval from cte
```

You can hardcode the values in the anchor of the query rather than `select ... from mytable` if you prefer (as shown in your example).

If the contract end dates do not exactly align to the start dates (modulo three months), you might want to adapt the `where` clause of the recursive member.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your point about contract end dates not aligning to start dates? We may have situations where the dates are like this 3-31-21 to 5-31-24. In this case, we would only want to capture the date when a full 6 months has elapsed, so the final iteration would only show 3-30-24, not 9-30-24. Edit: Actually, I think if I add the dateadd(month, 3, date_interval) into the where clause that solves it.

Comment: @StephenPoole: yes, exactly :)